# How to transpile a JSX file in command line

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I am pretty new to React, I tried to follow the topic about pretranspile JSX:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html

My code [app.js] is very simple:

```js
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var Todo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button>Add</button>;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, docuemtn.getElementById("div1"))
```

I first install:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
npm install react react-dom
```

Then try to use:

```
babel --watch ./app.js --out-dir ./
```

But it always says:

```
SyntaxError: ./app.jsx: Unexpected token (10:9)
   8 | var Todo = React.createClass({
   9 |  render: function() {
> 10 |          return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
     |          ^
  11 |  }
  12 | });
  13 |
```

**I wonder how to solve this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Babel 6 and up no longer has any native transforms for React. You have to add a preset like this

```
npm install babel-preset-react
```

And then run

```
babel --presets react --watch ./main.js --out-dir ./
```

Don't forget the `--presets react` part. After that it should work just fine.

Comment: @MagnusEngal Thanks, this works. I am pretty new to transpile and other modern workflow, another item I hear a lot is browserify, I wonder do you know any tutorial talking about it with babel 6 and how to make them work together?

Comment: I don't have a particular tutorial in mind, but you should look into babelify which basically is Browserify transform for Babel. https://github.com/babel/babelify

Comment: @MagnusEngal  Thanks, another question is: how do I specify the transpiled file name? Right now, it is always same as the JSX version as "app.js"

Comment: Replace `--out-dir ./` width `-o ./yourname.js`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: I find posts about babelify and browserify, but when I use commandline "browserify app.js -o bundle.js -t  babelify --presets react" I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. install babel together with plugin to tranform react-jsx

   ```
   npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
   ```
2. run below command to compile jsx file

   ```
   ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js --plugins transform-react-jsx test.jsx
   ```

Comment: This command seems to be not working. Getting some version related issue. babel-cli when installed takes version 6. something. the command expects more than 7.