# Can I use ANT to compile/transpile React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, ant

is it possible to compile React jsx code using Apache ANT? Before you ask "why", some background needed.
We currently have a relatively old webapp that is built with ANT scripts. Server code is Java, front end uses a mixture of JSF, Struts, JSP, and AngularJS (not the new Angular). (Yeah it grew organically and it's like showcase of the evolving web technologies!). So, as we all know AngularJS is obsolete, we'd like to see if we could include new UI design with React instead (that's another hurdle for another question).
So assuming somehow we create or acquire a bunch of React components we want to use, I gather the jsx would need to be compiled/tranpiled somehow to actual javascripts (unlike the AngularJS where we can just copy the file to right place). Normally with Nodes, we can somehow include Babel or something like that to do it.
So is that possible in ANT? (Or may be I should ask my other question of the sanity of mixing React in AngularJS first?)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, should be possible.  You can embed any command you need in an Ant build, so that could include transpile.  This might help with the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906541/how-to-transpile-a-jsx-file-in-command-line Ant exec task: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 0):

So, figured this out following the comments, tinkering with the ANT exec and installing Babel cli. Here's the steps:

1. install babel cli globally (so my build system have access on server without worry):
   `npm install --location=global @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react`
2. add definitions & targets to the build.xml, take jsx from jsx.src.dir and transpile to js in jsx.dst.dir:

Build.xml:

```
<property environment="env"/>   
<property name="jsx.src.dir" value="./src" />
<property name="jsx.dst.dir" value="./target/js" />
<condition property="jsx.cmd" value="cmd">
  <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<condition property="jsx.cmd" value="babel">
   <os family="unix"/>
</condition>

<condition property="jsx.arg" value="/c babel --presets @babel/preset-react ${jsx.src.dir} --out-dir ${jsx.dst.dir}">
  <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<condition property="jsx.arg" value=" --presets @babel/preset-react ${jsx.src.dir} --out-dir ${jsx.dst.dir}">
  <os family="unix"/>
</condition>

<target name="-transpile-jsx" description="transplie JSX" >
  <exec executable="${jsx.cmd}" failonerror="true">
     <arg line="${jsx.arg}"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="build" description="build app">
 <echo>building...</echo>
 <echo message="cmd=${jsx.cmd}"/>
 <echo message="arg=${jsx.arg}"/>
 <antcall target="-transpile-jsx" />
</target>
```